# How do I stop onmousedown from executing again

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of buttons that each add an image on the next click at the position of the click inside a specific div. However, I'm facing a problem that after I've clicked a button every click will add the image until I hit a different button. How can I make it so clicking the button only allows the onmousedown function to be called once?

Here is what I have:

```js
function makeSnow() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById("canvas").onmousedown = function() {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var pic = document.getElementById("snowballAppear");
    pic.style.display = '';
    pic.style.position = 'absolute';
    pic.style.left = x - 50 + 'px';
    pic.style.top = y - 50 + 'px';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  };
};

function makeCat() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById("canvas").onmousedown = function() {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var pic = document.getElementById("catAppear");
    pic.style.display = '';
    pic.style.position = 'absolute';
    pic.style.left = x - 50 + 'px';
    pic.style.top = y - 50 + 'px';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  };
};

function makeDog() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById("canvas").onmousedown = function() {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var pic = document.getElementById("dogAppear");
    pic.style.display = '';
    pic.style.position = 'absolute';
    pic.style.left = x - 50 + 'px';
    pic.style.top = y - 50 + 'px';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  };
};
```

```html
<div id="container" class "container">
  <div id='canvas' style="background-color: green; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  </div>
  <ul>
    <button onClick="makeSnow()">
    <li>snow</li>
    </button>
    <button onClick="makeCat()">
    <li>cat</li>
    </button>
    <button onClick="makeDog()">
    <li>dog</li>
    </button>
  </ul>
  <div class "picture">
    <img alt="snowballAppear" id="snowballAppear" style="display: none; width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/pottermore/images/9/99/Snowball-lrg.png/revision/latest?cb=20130412122815" />
  </div>
  <div class "picture">
    <img alt="catAppear" id="catAppear" style="display: none; width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
  </div>
  <div class "picture">
    <img alt="dogAppear" id="dogAppear" style="display: none; width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/39317/chihuahua-dog-puppy-cute-39317.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Disable the button after it's been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to bind an event to an element in JavaScript, the old fashionned spaghetti style that is much hated these days, the intermediate style with property affectation that is not so bad but not really a good practice, and the trendy style that is using `addEventListener`.

Old fashionned spaghetti style :

```js
function sayHello() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sayHello()">Say hello</button>
```

Intermediate style with property affectation :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = sayHello;

function sayHello() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Say hello</button>
```

Trendy style with `addEventListener` :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", sayHello);

function sayHello() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Say hello</button>
```

The last two styles avoid the HTML+JS soup. This is considered a good practice that helps to produce "unobstrusive JavaScript" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to the rescue). That being said, the third approach is often the best option in that it makes it easy to deal with multiple listeners :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", sayHello);
btn.addEventListener("click", sayGoodbye);

function sayHello() {
  console.log("hello");
}

function sayGoodbye() {
  console.log("goodbye");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Say hello and goodbye</button>
```

Now to solve the "one click, one picture" problem you need to stop listening whenever the user clicks on the button. To do this you can either reset the `onclick` property, or use a new function called `removeEventListener`. One snippet for both options :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = sayHello;
btn.addEventListener("click", sayGoodbye);

function sayHello() {
  console.log("hello");
  btn.onclick = null;
}

function sayGoodbye() {
  console.log("goodbye");
  btn.removeEventListener("click", sayGoodbye);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Say hello and goodbye once</button>
```

Another possibility would be to use a global variable combined with an `if` statement. Not a best practice, but I believe it's worth mentionning it :

```js
var shouldSayHello = false;
var masterBtn = document.getElementById("master-btn");
var slaveBtn = document.getElementById("slave-btn");

masterBtn.onclick = unlock;
slaveBtn.onclick = sayHello;
slaveBtn.style.color = "gray";

function unlock() {
  shouldSayHello = true;
  slaveBtn.style.color = "black";
}

function sayHello() {
  if (shouldSayHello) {
    console.log("hello");
    shouldSayHello = false;
    slaveBtn.style.color = "gray";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="master-btn">Unlock</button>
<button id="slave-btn">Say hello once</button>
```

All this to finally answer the actual question. Note that you have to clone the hidden image element with the `cloneNode` function in order to add multiple cats to the canvas (we only need cats for the demo) :

```js
var catBtn = document.getElementById("cat-btn");

catBtn.addEventListener("click", prepareCatLanding);

function prepareCatLanding() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", appendCat);
};

function appendCat() {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var src = document.getElementById("catAppear");
  this.removeEventListener("mousedown", appendCat);
  pic = src.cloneNode();
  pic.id = '';
  pic.style.display = '';
  pic.style.position = 'absolute';
  pic.style.left = x - 50 + 'px';
  pic.style.top = y - 50 + 'px';
  src.parentNode.appendChild(pic);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><button id="cat-btn">cat</button></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="canvas" style="background-color: green; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  </div>
  <div class="picture">
    <img alt="catAppear" id="catAppear" style="display: none; width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I've fixed the HTML along the way. Indeed, `<button><li></li></button>` is not valid since `<ul>` only accepts list items, it should be the opposite, that is `<li><button></button></li>`. Moreover, `class "container"` should be `class="container"`.

Comment: That is a later part of what I'm trying to do that I figured out already; however, I cut the code down for ease sake. I'm trying to make it so hitting the button only can add one image. Then hitting the button allows another picture to be added. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the `onmousedown` event listener with a function that does nothing, *in* the original `onmousedown` event listener. Like this:

```
function makeCat() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById("canvas").onmousedown = function() {
    ...
    document.getElementById("canvas").onmousedown = () => {};
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your event listener, you could reset the mousedown to something else that doesn't do anything:

```
function makeSnow() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById("canvas").onmousedown = function() {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var pic = document.getElementById("catAppear");
    pic.style.display = '';
    pic.style.position = 'absolute';
    pic.style.left = x - 50 + 'px';
    pic.style.top = y - 50 + 'px';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    document.getElementById("canvas").onmousedown = function() {
      //do nothing;
    };
  };
};
```

And then the same for the other functions.

Comment: Your function will replace the onmousedown event *directly* with an empty function, while it should only replace it if the function for onmousedown is initially called. So almost there, take a look at my answer.

Comment: That was correct, thanks, I had missed a brace that changed the whole meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `return;` statement in your functions to exit them.

Comment: I tried that inside the functions and it still adds the images.

Comment: Did you add it inside the `onmousedown` function or just inside the `makeSnow` function?

Comment: That ends the function, but doesn't stop additional onmousedowns from occuring. Which does answer my question. I need to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can return right after image is added, add an condition to your liking, I am not sure what exacly is your problem.

```
if (some condition) return;
```

But before anything:

`class "container"` and many more like it  is not how you write classes in HTML, the correct notation is `class="name"`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer suggests to redefine *onmousedown* event handler, which would work but requires you to write superfluous code. Here is shorter version by the way =).

```
document.getElementById("canvas").onmousedown = null;
```

It seems like a simple event listener which triggers only once is a suitable solution as well.

```
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("mousedown", functionToExecuteOnceEventOccurs, { once: true });
```

Take a look at [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Pay attention to browser compatibility table though, "once" option is not that widely supported.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

`break;` or `return;` at the end of each function